# Get only first match in if

Tags: javascript

"if" gives me more answers.. How to get only first? Thanks people.
http://jsfiddle.net/TsxBy/

```
var content = "var=xyz-id=2,var=abc-id=1,var=bcd-id=7,var=abc-id=1,var=hij-id=4,var=xyz-id=2";
content = content.split(',');
for (i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    var temp = content[i].match(/\d/);
    if (temp == '1') {
        alert('match 1'); // how to response only first "matched"?
    }
    if (temp == '2') {
        alert('match 2'); // same here
    }
}
```

Comment: `match` returns an array. Warning, `i` is global

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand your issue a bit. Please check this **[fiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/rgin/TsxBy/7/)** if it's what you need.

```
var content = "var=xyz-id=2,var=abc-id=1,var=bcd-id=7,var=abc-id=1,var=hij-id=4,var=xyz-id=2";

content = content.split(',');
var ctr1 = 0, ctr2 = 0;

for (i = 0; i < content.length; i++) { 

    var temp = content[i].match(/\d/);
    console.log(temp[0]);

    if (temp[0] == '1' && ctr1 == 0) {
        alert('match 1');
        ctr1++;
    }
    if (temp[0] == '2' && ctr2 == 0) {
        alert('match 2');
        ctr2++;
    } 
}
```

Comment: sorry i mean the first different number of all " **1** **2** 3 4 1 2 "

Comment: That worked?! Haha. I thought you wanted something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rgin/TsxBy/9/

Answer (score 0):

Your code is checking for a single integer in each element of the array, resulting in 6 iterated checks, 4 of which have a matching number to one of your if statements, which is what you get, 4 alerts.

If you want it to stop looking after it matches the first number, use a *break* at the end of the desired if statement.